# SAPUI5 - add Fragment in SimpleForm

Tags: sapui5

i have a problem with adding an fragment to an SimpleForm in SAPUI5. I have an SimpleForm and want to add content in the form with fragments. The result should look like this:
[what i want done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsZzl.png)

my fragment:

```html
<core:FragmentDefinition 
 xmlns="sap.m" 
 xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
 xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" 
 xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
 xmlns:tnt="sap.tnt" 
 xmlns:custom="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1">

  <core:Title text="{i18n>beauskunftung.suche.address}"/>
  <Label text="{i18n>beauskunftung.suche.streetNo}"/>
  <Input editable="false" fieldGroupIds="Address" value="{AddressStreet}" id="inputStreetID"></Input>
  <Input editable="false" fieldGroupIds="Address" value="{AddressStreetNumber}" id="inputNumberID">
   <layoutData>
    <l:GridData span="L3 M3 S4"/>
   </layoutData>
  </Input>
  <Label text="{i18n>beauskunftung.suche.zipCity}"/>
  <Input editable="false" fieldGroupIds="Address" value="{AddressZipCode}" id="inputZipID">
   <layoutData>
    <l:GridData span="L3 M3 S4"/>
   </layoutData>
  </Input>
  <Input editable="false" fieldGroupIds="Address" value="{AddressCity}" id="inputCityID"/>

</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

if i add the fragment with javacript

```js
 var oFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment("testistest", "com.natuvion.ddi.fragments.select.address");
  var oLayout = this.getView().byId("AddressIDandSoOn");
  oLayout.insertContent(oFragment, -1);
```

i get the following error:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: "Element sap.ui.core.Title#__title0,Element sap.m.Label#__label0,Element sap.m.Input#testistest--inputStreetID,Element sap.m.Input#testistest--inputNumberID,Element sap.m.Label#__label1,Element sap.m.Input#testistest--inputZipID,Element sap.m.Input#testistest--inputCityID" is not valid for aggregation "content" of Element sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm#__xmlview1--AddressIDandSoOn

I think the problem is that the add method can just add one element (if I have just a label in the fragment it works!). I looked for some element which should contains all the elements from the fragment but I didn't find one. If I add the fragment via XML on the page

```
<core:Fragment id="addressFragment1" 
fragmentName="com.natuvion.ddi.fragments.select.address" type="XML"> 
</core:Fragment>
```

it works. At this point I have no idea how to add fragments inside an SimpleForm. I need the dynamic generation of the elements, as I have to add this depending on the given data, possibly also several times

My Question:
 - How can i add an Fragment to an SimpleForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programatic APIs add/insert content support only single element and not an array. So you could try looping over the array and add one by one:

```js
  var aFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment("testistest", "com.natuvion.ddi.fragments.select.address");
  var oLayout = this.getView().byId("AddressIDandSoOn");
  aFragment.forEach(function (oElement) {oLayout.addContent(oElement);});
```

Another option you can consider is moving to sap.ui.layout.form.Form. It has composed aggregations inside: Form -> formContainers -> formElements -> label,fields[].

It looks like the address fragment could be a single FormContainer and then you could add it to the Form in a single call to addFormContainer().